# Add text before and after a particular string javascripts

Tags: javascript, regex, replace

I am trying to put add a text before and after two particular words in a string.For example.

```
"There is a cat and a dog"
```

Lets say the characters are "cat" and "dog" and additions are "white" and "black".The text should change to

```
"There is a white cat and a black dog"
```

I have managed to do it using replace but is there any cleaner way to do it.

```
function colorData(tagsText)
{
    tagsText = tagsText.replace(/cat/g, "white cat");
    tagsText = tagsText.replace(/dog/g, "black dog");
    return tagsText;
}
```

Comment: Your own method looks quite clean and readable to me. what is your concern with it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have many key -> value replacements you could use a map:

```
var map = { cat: 'white', dog: 'black' };
tagsText.replace(/\b(cat|dog)\b/g, function(match) {
  return map[match] + " " + match;
});
```

Or a dynamic regex:

```
var regex = new RegExp('\\b(' + Object.keys(map).join('|') + ')\\b', 'g');
tagsText.replace(regex, function(match) {
  return map[match] + " " + match;
});
```

Comment: Note that \ when used inside `RegExp` constructor should be double escaped. Use `new RegExp('\\b('...`

Comment: Also, there is no need of capturing group

Comment: @Tushar Well should me capturing group or non capturing group, with the later I need an extra two bytes.

Comment: what if i want to add the "black" after the dog in the dynamic regex?

Comment: @soldiershin You could remove the `" " + match` part and write the full replacement in `map = { dog: 'dog black' }`

Answer (score 5):

You may use anonymous function inside `replace` function.

```js
var s = "There is a cat and a dog";
alert(s.replace(/\b(?:cat|dog)\b/g, function(x){
   return (x == 'cat' ? 'white ' : 'dark ' ) + x;
}));
```

Comment: Good catch on `\b` ^1

Answer (score 2):

You can chain the `replace` calls

```
return tagsText.replace(/cat/g, "white cat").replace(/dog/g, 'black dog');
```

You can also use an object to keep the key-values and use it in the [`replace`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace#Specifying_a_function_as_a_parameter) callback.

```
var replacements = {
    cat: 'white cat',
    dog: 'black dog'
};

function colorData(tagsText) {
    return tagsText.replace(/cat|dog/g, (x) => replacements[x]);
}
```

```js
var replacements = {
    cat: 'white cat',
    dog: 'black dog'
};

function colorData(tagsText) {
    return tagsText.replace(/cat|dog/g, (x) => replacements[x]);
}


var str = "There is a cat and a dog";

document.body.innerHTML = colorData(str);
```

Comment: May be `|` but I am not sure :(